# ElasticSearch: Use output of one index to sort documents of another index

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, join, indexing

I have one index, lets say book and another index writer. Book index contains the ids for the docs of writer index. Now I want to sort the books on the basis on writers name.
Book index:
`"book": { "properties": { "name": { "type": "text" }, "writerId": { "type": "long" } }`

Writer index:
`"writer": { "properties": { "id": { "type": "long" }, "name": { "type": "text" } }`

For search books by writer's name I can get the ids from writer index and feed it to search query for book. but for sorting I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Since a writer will never change once a book has been written, why don't you store the writer's name into the book index (i.e. denormalize)?

Comment: @Val In my case lets suppose writer name can change and there can be many books for one writer, so when I need to update the writer's name I will also need to update the book's document which contains same writer name and that could be heavy operation so trying to avoid it.